# Chrome default button style

Tags: html, css, button, stylesheet

Is it possbile to get the default Chrome button style in CSS?

Of course many would say use http://pastebin.com/zjkW2cJe or http://pastebin.com/xKGBZFPg

But i want this button CSS code...

Comment: There's one interesting style property: `-webkit-appearance`. Google it =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want the pure CSS rules, you can inspect the button element and check out the entries saying "user agent stylesheet".

In my Chrome 9, they look like this:

```
input, textarea, keygen, select, button, isindex, datagrid {
margin: 0em;
font: -webkit-small-control;
color: initial;
letter-spacing: normal;
word-spacing: normal;
....... etc. much more
```

however, if you literally want the rules for natively rendering a button, in order to render the same button in other browsers, I think that's impossible: A default button will be rendered by the Browser's UI or even the underlying operating system. In my Windows 7, the default button looks like this:

[image]

This style, as far as I know, is not in the CSS rules. You would have to rebuild it using background images, borders, rounded corners etc. If you don't mind using jQuery,  libraries like [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) have seducingly simple solutions for this.

Answer (score 2):

You want them... visually? If so, inspect the element and look at the computed styles.

Answer (score 0):

In current Chrome on macOS, it is something like this:

```
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #e4e4e4, #f7f7f7);
border: 1px solid #afafaf
```