# Why is the default CSS lost when changing button's background color?

Tags: jquery, css, background-color

I have observed a very weird issue which reason I cannot wholly grasp. Thus I want to ask you guys for an explanation of what is happening that I loose the default `CSS` on a button when I change its background color with jQuery?

This is [demonstrated in the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Boro/899Wn/3/) (tested on `FF` and `Chrome`). If you will mouse over the button it will loose its style, e.g. no rounded borders, which is not what one would expect to happen. **Can you please explain why it is happening so? Also what workaround would you suggest to preserve the default 'CSS' settings?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the button's background colour in css to begin with then animate it back to that colour in your jQuery that will do the trick.

http://jsfiddle.net/899Wn/8/

```
button {
    background: blue;
}


$("#nav ul li button").hover(function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({
        backgroundColor: '#E5E5E5'
    }, 500);
}, function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({
        backgroundColor: 'blue'
    }, 500);
})
```

Comment: Thanks for that (+1). I tried it myself as well. Though this is sufficient for the final product where I will use my styles, in this question I am wondering how to **preserve the defaults**.

Comment: As far as I'm aware you can't animate it back to default as the browser will render the button in it's default state according to each individual browser. I think that my solution is the best approach as far as I can see.

Comment: Thank you all for the answers. I accept Billy's answer as it was posted first and he also showed the code sample. Cheers all.

Answer (score 1):

Has soon you start stylize a form element ie. a < button href="#" > tag, especially with background-color or borders, the browser re-render the element. Then, it shows YOUR specific .css and you loose 'browser + software +o.s.' specific styling.

[styling form controls introduction](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200410/styling_even_more_form_controls/)  and  [styling form controls in details](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200701/styling_form_controls_with_css_revisited/)

Comment: +1 thanks for the links. Interesting read. I see from them and your answers guys that the only option appears to forget about the defaults and just always play with your own CSS.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the default button on the page is a system generated button (ie. Windows). Changing any of the visually affecting styles will cause your browser to render the button, removing certain styles. Once you get here there is now way back. The best thing to do is style button up to look very similar, then you can modify individual styles without losing the rest. Similar answer here: [Chrome default button style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5031979/chrome-default-button-style). I'll see if I can find some more information on the matter.

**EDIT:**

The second answer on this page seems to back up my thoughts, although still no reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10265336/719718

Comment: Thanks (+1). Yea I had taken another look and yea it must be that thought the buttons are slightly different in different browsers they are system (in my case Win) buttons.